# How put a value in a legend

Tags: graphics, legending, text, plot-themes

I am trying to put in a legend a value calculated previously but as you can see by your self the output is so stranger.

```
 f[x_] := ((3/20)^(471/100)*20/29*(x - 80))^(50/
     91) + ((3/20)^(471/100)*20/29*(x - 60))^(50/91) - 1/25
x0 = Extract[{x} /. FindRoot[f[x] == 0, {x, 80}], 1];
P0 = Point[{x0, 0}];
Gf = Plot[f[x], {x, 80, 100}, PlotStyle -> Red, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
   PlotLegends -> {LineLegend[{Red}, {"f(x)"}], 
     PointLegend[{Black}, {"P0=("  x0 ",0)"}]}];
Show[Gf, Graphics[{PointSize[0.015], P0}]]
```

So could someone help me to put in the legend `P0=(x0,0)` with `x0`=numerical solution?

Comment: ```Subscript[G, f] = 
  Plot[f[x], {x, 80, 100}, PlotStyle -> Red, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
   PlotLegends -> {LineLegend[{Red}, {"f(x)"}], 
     PointLegend[{Black}, {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(0\)]\)=(" <> 
        ToString@Subscript[x, 0] <> ",0)"}]}];```

Comment: @Syed Oh, thanks!!! Could I ask to you where in Wolfram Documentation can I found any information about resolution?

Comment: @Syed Okay, thanks for the help. See you soon.

Comment: I believe you want to look at `NumberForm`. (corrected spellings of the command and deleted the comment with the mistake). `ToString@NumberForm[
  x0 , {6, 3}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also add the point using [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) and use a single [`LineLegend`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineLegend.html):

```
legend = LineLegend[{Red, Directive[Black, PointSize[Large]]}, 
  {"f(x)", Row[{"P0 = (", Round[x0, .01], ",", 0, ")"}]}, 
  Joined -> {True, False}]

Plot[f[x], {x, 80, 100}, PlotStyle -> Red, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"},
 Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[Large], Point@{x0, 0}}, 
 PlotLegends -> legend]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use the options [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) + [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) + [`MeshStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshStyle.html) to add the black point:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 80, 100},
 PlotStyle -> Red, AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"},
 MeshFunctions -> {#2 &},
 Mesh -> {{0}},
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Black, PointSize[Large]],
 PlotLegends -> legend]
```

[image]